# Is it possible to express a field type dependent on another parametric type?

Tags: julia

As an artificial example suppose I have a parametric struct where `T <: AbstractFloat`

```
mutable struct Summary{T<:AbstractFloat}

    count
    sum::T

end
```

I would like to type the `count` field as `UInt16` when `T === Float16` or as `UInt32` when `T === Float32` and as `UInt64` in all other cases.

My current approach is to use a union type `Union{UInt16, UInt32, UInt64}` for the `count` field

```
module SummaryStats

export Summary, avg

const CounterType = Union{UInt16, UInt32, UInt64}

mutable struct Summary{T<:AbstractFloat}

    count::CounterType
    sum::T
    # explicitly typed no-arg constructor
    Summary{T}() where {T<:AbstractFloat} = new(_counter(T), zero(T))
end

# untyped no-arg constructor defaults to Float64
Summary() = Summary{Float64}()

function avg(summary::Summary{T})::T where {T <: AbstractFloat}
    if summary.count > zero(_counter(typeof(T)))
        summary.sum / summary.count
    else
        zero(T)
    end
end

# internal helper functions, not exported
Base.@pure _counter(::Type{Float16})::UInt16 = UInt16(0)
Base.@pure _counter(::Type{Float32})::UInt32 = UInt32(0)
Base.@pure _counter(::DataType)::UInt64 = UInt64(0)

end # module
```

This seems to work but, obviously, `@code_warntype` is not happy with the union type for the `count` field.

I am wondering whether it is possible to somehow compute the correct concrete type according to the rules laid out above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ["outer-only" constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/constructors/#Outer-only-constructors-1) are mainly for these kinda use cases:

```
julia> const CounterType = Union{UInt16, UInt32, UInt64}
Union{UInt16, UInt32, UInt64}

julia> mutable struct Summary{T<:AbstractFloat, S<:CounterType}
           count::S
           sum::T
           function Summary{T}() where {T<:AbstractFloat}
               S = T === Float16 ? UInt16 : 
                   T === Float32 ? UInt32 :
                   T === Float64 ? UInt64 : throw(ArgumentError("unexpected type: $(T)!"))
               new{T,S}(zero(S), zero(T))
           end
       end

julia> Summary() = Summary{Float64}()
Summary

julia> function avg(summary::Summary{T})::T where {T <: AbstractFloat}
       if summary.count > zero(summary.count)
           summary.sum / summary.count
       else
           zero(T)
       end
   end
avg (generic function with 1 method)

julia> avg(Summary())
0.0

julia> @code_warntype avg(Summary())
Body::Float64
1 ─ %1 = (Base.getfield)(summary, :count)::UInt64
│   %2 = (Base.ult_int)(0x0000000000000000, %1)::Bool
└──      goto #3 if not %2
2 ─ %4 = (Base.getfield)(summary, :sum)::Float64
│   %5 = (Base.getfield)(summary, :count)::UInt64
│   %6 = (Base.uitofp)(Float64, %5)::Float64
│   %7 = (Base.div_float)(%4, %6)::Float64
└──      return %7
3 ─      return 0.0

julia> @code_warntype avg(Summary{Float32}())
Body::Float32
1 ─ %1 = (Base.getfield)(summary, :count)::UInt32
│   %2 = (Base.ult_int)(0x00000000, %1)::Bool
└──      goto #3 if not %2
2 ─ %4 = (Base.getfield)(summary, :sum)::Float32
│   %5 = (Base.getfield)(summary, :count)::UInt32
│   %6 = (Base.uitofp)(Float32, %5)::Float32
│   %7 = (Base.div_float)(%4, %6)::Float32
└──      return %7
3 ─      return 0.0f0
```

Comment: +1 Neat! IIUC, the Float32 avg() call needs to convert between UInt32 and UInt64 for the comparison with 0 (`(Core.zext_int)(Core.UInt64, %1)::UInt64`). Out of curiosity, could that be avoided?

Comment: yep. `summary.count > zero(summary.count)`